# How can I re-enable "never show" notifications in Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: xubuntu, notification

I've pressed the button "Never show again" on the notification related to the successful connection to a VPN network.

How can I re-enable this notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be in the gconf settings for nm-applet.  Try installing gconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Then run it:

```
gconf-editor
```

And go to /apps/nm-applet and make sure 'disable-connected-notifications' and 'disable-disconnected-notifications' are disabled (unchecked).